# Print without scientific notation

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I have is,

```
>>a= 100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560
>>print(a)
>>1e+50
```

How do I print 'a' in non-scientific notation form with zero decimal places in Python 2.7?

Comment: Have you tried `print(str(a))`?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9FWwdAADZibGVmam1lamBgaWBpaWJgbGBgbWZpYmplYmhtYmpiZmhlwFRRl5pVoJGr@/w8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Unable to reproduce this in Python3.7 and Python 2.7

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it gives me the whole number.